# How to send syslog without TLS with python and sysloghandler?

Tags: python, ssl, syslog

I would like to send syslog without TLS.
I'm using a custom python tool to log the syslog over TCP and to this point, it works.
But I need to send the syslogs without the TLS.

i'm using the pyhton SysLogHandler method with the option socket.SOCK_STREAM  for TCP but there are no options restricting the TLS parts.

I read the doc about SysLogHandler and I did not seen anyways to deactivate the TLS.
Is there a way to send TCP syslog without TLS?

I thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing about TLS in the [standard library's `logging.handlers.SysLogHandler`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ab030d6f9d73e7f6c2213c2e308d1ceb04761485/Lib/logging/handlers.py#L709) implementation. (The next handler, for SMTP, does speak about TLS.)

So I'd imagine just

```
handler = SysLogHandler(('some-host', 12345), socktype=socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

should pipe syslog messages over TCP to some-host:12345.